# Retrieving data from a Text Input and sending it to an api

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an application in React Native to experiment with this and I made a bee in Django to retrieve data and send data.

For example, how can I send my data from an input text via a post to django?

For example for get I use something like this

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState({});

  const todoData = () => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.1.5:8000/app/todo-data/')
        .then(response => setTodos(response.data))
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was an error!', error);
        });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    todoData();
  }, []);
```

My question is how could I put in a "state" what data I want to send?

In Django I want to send this

```
{
  "item":"how to make"
}
```

I want to send an item with a text as a post

And this is my TextInput

```
<View style={styles.container}>
       <Header />
       <View style={styles.header}>
         <View style={styles.content}>
           <View style={styles.list}>
             <TextInput style={styles.textInput} editable maxLength={40}/>
              <FlatList data={todos} renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <TodoItem item={item} pressHandler={pressHandler} />
              )}>
            </FlatList>
           </View>
         </View>
       </View>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get input value to state you can use TextInput onChange callback.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange

```
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(null)

  <TextInput 
    value={inputValue}
    onChange={(val) => setInputValue(val)}
  />
```

Then you can include inputValue in POST request.